# Triggering a function when administrator enables a user in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-workflow

I'm trying to do a web application in which the user creates a account in the /extranet domain and its disabled initially.
When the sitecore admin enables the user account an function should be triggered so that a mail can be sent to the user, But i'm not finding any solution to trigger the code.

This is the code i have used to create the user in /extranet

```
Membership.CreateUser(mailId, password, mailId, "question", "answer", false, out status);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer:
[**http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/06/15/notify-sitecore-user-on-account-enable/**](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/06/15/notify-sitecore-user-on-account-enable/)
for a complete example of overriding the corresponding command.

You will need to replace 
`<command name="usermanager:enable" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.UserManager.Enable,Sitecore.Kernel"/>`

with 
`<command name="usermanager:enable" type="Sitecore72.Classes.EnableUserNotify, Sitecore72"/>`

You could use the reflected code from Sitecore.Kernel.dll, and append your logic for notification in the Run method - where args.IsPostBack is true, after the user profile has been updated (user.IsApproved = true;)

This would enable you to retain the message boxes as implemented by sitecore and add the custom functionality you need as well.

Comment: Works like a charm...!! Even-though im having few difficulties in understanding the working since im a newbie, it seems like a perfect solution.

Comment: Good to hear and thanks for marking this as the answer!
Sitecore lists the various event handlers triggered by actions in their UI in the form od commands, and since its configurable, it gives us the power to override any default handler.
This solution basically copied over sitecore's default handler and added a line for sending out the emails we wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a command that gets executed (`<command name="usermanager:enable" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.UserManager.Enable,Sitecore.Kernel"/>`) - which you can find in the `Commands.config` file in the `App_Config` folder - when you click on the Enable button, so you could override that with your own code (don't forget to also run that `Enable` functionality of course.